# How to get or write exact xpath for selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, webdriver

How to get or write exact xpath for selenium?
the code in inspect element is [xpath for Country already added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5x4r.png)

```
<li>Country already added</li>
```

Comment: For Page object model

Comment: Can you share your code trials?

Comment: What do you expect to do with the element and what code have you already tried

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Xpath:-

```
//*[@class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable"]//*[text()="Country already added"]
```

Comment: @satheesh-kumar-p I have marked your edit as a rejection; if you have a suggestion for a different way of finding xpaths, that deserves to be an answer of its own instead of an edit to a different answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath

```
//*[text()='Country already added']
```

or

```
//li[contains(text(),'Country already added')]
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below xpath:

```
//li[contains(text(),'Country already added')]
```

or:

```
//div[@class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable']/ul/li[1]
```